# Bathroom Cabinet Hinge

Tags: bathroom, cabinets, hinges

I have been looking for a replacement hinge for my bathroom cabinet to no avail.  I was hoping some smart people here would be able to suggest a hinge that will work for me based on the photos I attached.  If I need to take any additional pictures in order to help me solve this mystery, please let me know.  I have checked Home Depot and Lowe's and the hinge selection they have doesn't solve the issue.

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYZBp.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! It appears that you need what's called a "European style hinge". I'm not really sure exactly what the question is, though, and what you're not able to find. If it's a matter of sizing, you could try a specialist woodworking store (_Rockler_ and _Woodcrafters_ are two major US chains and are an example of what I mean - that's not an explicit recommendation of either), and they'll probably have a wider selection. If this doesn't answer your question, please [edit] your post clarify exactly what your issue is.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's a 'full overlay' hinge. @FreeMan is right: you need to go to a specialty hardware store with that hinge and match it up. Bring the base plate that's still in the cabinet, as that matters.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate The new hinge may well come with a base plate that will replace the existing one. Though, it would be handy to be able to match up the mounting holes for that piece, if at all possible.

Comment: @FreeMan -- it's not that... different mounting plates have different offsets. (Not huge -- a mm or two -- but you want to get as close as possible.)

Comment: @FreeMan and AloysiusDefenestrate thank you for the replies.  I looked at the websites you suggested.  I have attached a few more pictures in order to show the working hinge as it is in the cabinet right now.  I hope this helps.  I think the hinge I have hyperlinked will work, but I welcome your thoughts based on the new pics I added.  https://www.rockler.com/blum-soft-close-110-blumotion-inset-clip-top-hinges-for-face-frame-cabinets

Comment: My thoughts are, "that looks like a hinge". Do you have a specific question? You said you're looking for a replacement and you hope someone here can make a suggestion. I offered the general name of the hinge, @AloysiusDefenestrate suggested the type. You still haven't asked an actual question. Edit your post to tell us all about the _problem_. From the last pic it looks like the door is hanging crooked, but that could be because you took a hinge off to take pics of it.

Comment: Is the mounting plate attached to the back of the face frame on the cabinet? Your linked item might work, as would a bunch of other face frame-specific models. The key is whether your door is inset or overlay. (Linked ones are for inset only.) If that fails, draw a scale diagram of how the hinge attaches to the cabinet, how the door sits relative to the cabinet face frame and how far you expect the door to swing (in degrees).

Comment: @freeman I stated I am trying to replace a broken hinge.  I stated that I have tried multiple hinges from Lowe's and Home Depot.  My question was and is, what is the correct hinge I need to purchase to complete the repair.  I am thankful you gave me some tips.  Yes that is correct, the door is crooked because the bottom hinge is the one that broke.  There are no markings on the hinge to lead me to selecting the correct replacement hinge.  At Aloysius Defenestrate, yes the hinge plate mounts to the back of the cabinet face.  The cabinet has two doors and the one on the right has issues.

Comment: Once again, take the broken hinge (and the good one, for good measure) to a _woodworking specialist store_. They'll have a _lot_ more knowledge, and if they don't have your exact replacement in stock, they'll be able to order it. They'll also know what measurements to take to ensure you get the right one the first time. If you don't have one of the "brand name" stores I mentioned in my first comment, go to a lumber mill. They probably won't have door hinges in stock, but they may be able to tell you how to measure to order it, or point you to local folk who can help.